# Add an X to the end of a div with pure CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to add a small X on the right side of my `<span>`. I went through some existing solutions but couldn't find a clean (and fairly simple) solution.

Here's a mock-up of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Here's what I have so far:

```css
.categoryTag {
   display:inline-block;
   background-color:#eaeaea;
   border-radius:4px;
   padding:6px;
   font-size:12px;
   cursor:pointer;
   margin:4px;
}
```

```html
<span class="categoryTag">category 1</span>
<span class="categoryTag">category 2</span>
<span class="categoryTag">category 3</span>
```

**Note** that `content: 'X'` would match the same font as the `span`, while I need a different color and font size.

Any suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: `.categoryTag:after {content: 'X'; ... }`

Comment: Did you have a look at my answer is that what you want ?

Comment: @Zvezdas1989 Yeah I upvoted it, but Mohammad answered first...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a pseudo element:

```css
.categoryTag {
   display:inline-block;
   background-color:#eaeaea;
   border-radius:4px;
   position: relative;
   padding:6px;
   padding-right: 25px;
   font-size:12px;
   cursor:pointer;
   margin:4px;
}

.categoryTag.medium {
  padding-right: 35px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.categoryTag.large {
  padding-right: 45px;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.categoryTag::after {
   content: 'X';
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   right: 10px;
   transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<span class="categoryTag">category 1</span>
<span class="categoryTag medium">category 2</span>
<span class="categoryTag large">category 3</span>
```

Comment: Note that `content: 'X'` would match the same font as the span, while I need a different color and font size.

Comment: `:after` is deprecated CSS2 syntax. Please use `::after` instead.

Comment: @KobyDouek You can add `color`, `font-size` properties to make an `X` look like exactly you want.

Comment: @MohammadUsman Thanks that would do the job. Don't know why my question was downvoted though

Comment: @MohammadUsman Could you change the font color to `darkgray` and set font size of `9px` so I can accept your answer? Right now your snippet is showing the same font.

Comment: @KobyDouek You can make any changes in your project that you want by adding/modifying css properties of `::after` pseudo element.

Answer (score 3):

**In my opinion, the text `X` in the style will be affected by the font used on the website. So it's better to use this alternative**

```css
.categoryTag {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 4px;
}


.categoryTag::after,
.categoryTag::before {
  content: '';
  height: 13px; /* tweak this change the size of the X */
  top:50%;
  width: 2px; /* tweak this change the thickness of the X */
  background: #000; /* change this change the color of the X */
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 13px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
.categoryTag::before {
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="categoryTag">category 1</span>
<span class="categoryTag medium">category 2</span>
<span class="categoryTag large">category 3</span>
```

**With some small transition -**

```css
.categoryTag {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 6px;
  padding-right: 25px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 4px;
}


.categoryTag::after,
.categoryTag::before {
  content: '';
  height: 8px; /* tweak this change the size of the X */
  top:50%;
  width: 1px; /* tweak this change the thickness of the X */
  background: #000; /* change this change the color of the X */
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
  position: absolute;
  right: 14px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.3s;
}
.categoryTag.two:before,.categoryTag.two:after{
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(89deg);;
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(89deg);;
  -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(89deg);
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(89deg);
}
.categoryTag::before {
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
.categoryTag:hover:before,.categoryTag:hover:after{
  height: 13px;
  width: 2px;
  right: 13px;
}
.categoryTag.two:hover:after{
  height: 13px;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.categoryTag.two:hover:before {
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-45deg);
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<span class="categoryTag">category 1</span>
<span class="categoryTag two">category 2</span>
```

I hope this was helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - a very interesting direction. I will look into this. +1 from me.

Comment: @KobyDouek in this way if you want you can combine the **X** with some transition to.

Comment: Yeah I can see the benifits of drawing lines instead of font. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pseudo element after:

**Here is the sample code**

```css
.categoryTag {
   display:inline-block;
   background-color:#eaeaea;
   border-radius:4px;
   padding:6px;
   font-size:12px;
   cursor:pointer;
   margin:4px;
}

.categoryTag::after {
  content: ' x';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<span class="categoryTag">category 1</span>
<span class="categoryTag">category 2</span>
<span class="categoryTag">category 3</span>
```

[**codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QOgRYO)

*More on [after](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after)*

Answer (score 2):

Although having `content` in your css may work, I would recommend having an additional `span` instead because not all browsers support `content`. It's still totally up to you though.

```css
.categoryTag {
   display:inline-block;
   background-color:#eaeaea;
   border-radius:4px;
   padding:6px;
   font-size:12px;
   cursor:pointer;
   margin:4px;
}
.close {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="categoryTag">category 1 <span class="close">x</span></span>
<span class="categoryTag">category 2 <span class="close">x</span></span>
<span class="categoryTag">category 3 <span class="close">x</span></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I upvoted it, but It's not what I'm looking for, I wanted a putr CSS solution

Comment: Alright then, I had an assumption that you may want to handle some click events to close or hide the parent `span` or something like that @KobyDouek. Glad you got your solution though :)

Comment: Thanks @Dumisani, I hope others will find your answer helpful !

Answer (score 2):

I thought I'd add my way, just in case. I never think it's worth over complicating things but in this instance, I think it's worth using a [hex code](https://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) to get a better character than an 'X' (I've used the multiplication symbol).

Also vertically aligning your text to the centre will make the everything pleasing to the eye, or at least it does for me.

These are the 4 lines of CSS needed.

```
.categoryTag::after {
  content: ' \D7';
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**EXAMPLE:**

```css
.categoryTag {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-size: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 4px;
}

.categoryTag::after {
  content: ' \D7';
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span class="categoryTag">Category 1</span>
<span class="categoryTag">Category 2</span>
<span class="categoryTag">Category 3</span>
```

I hope you find this helpful.

Comment: That is great - I was looking for a way to make the `X` look "square". I'm using your solution, but since I accepted an answer of a guy who answered first and gave a lot of effort, I'll keep his answer as accepted. +1 from me thought. Thanks!